# How to grant full access to a windows drive for a domain user when it became lost

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, user-permissions

I have a UserAccount: UserAccount123, it is part of the admin group of the local computer.
The computer has Windows 7 Enterprise Installed (64bit) and it is part of a domain.
The user is a user on that domain and all users of the domain are in the users group of the computer.
There are only 2 drives on the computer (c and d)
The user can create a file on the c drive, but when trying on the d drive, it gets the error: Destination Folder Access Denied (you need permission to perform this action).
The owner of the c drive is TrustedInstaller
The owner of the d drive is TrustedInstaller (I just changed it back, after it was administrators and before that SYSTEM, but before that it was TrustedInstaller.)

I am not sure why the permissions on the D drive got changed. Right now, Authenticated Users, SYSTEM, Administrators, Users all have full permissions (everything is ticked apart from special permissions.) All sub fodlers, items and containers in the D drive also have inherited permissions from the D.

If anyone has any ideas to help get this domain user, who is an admin of the box via the administrators group, full access back on the d drive, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take ownership of the drive or the data folders on it, but replace the ownsership for all directories, subdirectories, etc.. Then set your permissions as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We did just that with a different account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We logged in with a domain admin account and applied the ownership to be TrustedInstaller for subdir and all items. Then we changed the administrators and system to have full control and applied that too to all sub folders and items. Then we restarted the machine and it's working correctly now.